# How to Handle Touch Event to pull down the text view

Tags: android, events

I've the following code and I want to generate event when I pull down the textView.
but my code generate events every time when I touch the screen.

```
final TextView pullDown=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

             pullDown.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {


            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

                first.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                pullDown.setHeight(200);
                pullDown.setText("Loading");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
            else if(event.getAction()==android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                first.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                change.setText("OK");
                pullDown.setText("Pull Down to Refresh");
                pullDown.setHeight(70);
            }

                return true;
        }

    });`
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'pulldown' ? did you mean something like dragging the textview ?

Comment: What do you actually mean by pull down ? Do you want to dynamically change the position of the textview ?

Comment: ya its like dragging text view.

Comment: when I click on text view I want to change the position of text view and other contents in application to down side..

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your requirement is : you have a button, when you click down, it does a time-costing operation, and you want the button shows "Loading", when the work is done, the button show "Pull down to refresh" Again.

According to this situation, you can't simply change the button by setText and Sleep(1000), this will make your screen no responseable during the second(Because it runs in Main UI Thread). So you can't see the change... Plz try use Thread+Handler or AsyncTask

```
class BtnAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        first.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        pullDown.setHeight(200);
        pullDown.setText("Loading");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        first.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        change.setText("OK");
        pullDown.setText("Pull Down to Refresh");
        pullDown.setHeight(70);
    }

}
```

and new a task when click the button, call:

```
new BtnAsyncTask().execute();
```

——————————————
Or you simple want a change in look when the button being clicked, use a drawable sytle

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/select_drawable" />

<item android:state_window_focused="true" 
      android:state_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/normal_drawalbe" />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/normal_drawalbe" />
```

hope it can help u :)

Comment: I think u didn't understand ma question I'll give u example.. In android mobile when we open menu and touch the screen and drag to downside it feels like all the elements r moving to down.. and i want like that when i touch on text view and drag down all the elements on that page drags downside...

Comment: I see. Maybe you can try Animation or make a custom view then, what you did would block the UI Thread, so you can't see any change.